# network receiver is not working

Tags: android

I try to implement the network receiver, here is my following code:

```
   package com.example.androidtablayout;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.util.Log;

public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { // <1>
 public static final String TAG = "NetworkReceiver";
 boolean isConnected = true;
Context c;
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


  boolean isNetworkDown = intent.getBooleanExtra(
    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);  // <2>

  if (isNetworkDown) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: NOT connected, stopping UpdaterService");
   // context.stopService(new Intent(context, UpdaterService.class)); // <3>
   } else {
       Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: connected, starting UpdaterService");
   //  context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdaterService.class)); // <4>
    }
  }

 }
```

In the Manifest.xml

```
      <application>
       <receiver android:name=".NetworkReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
      </receiver> 
   </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

My problem is when I switch off the wifi, the log still shows that "Connected",

I think the the network receiver didn't receiver the intenet connectivity correctly.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does onReceive() get fired when you turn off the WiFi?

Comment: yes, it is, I can see the log message underneath

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the onReceive() method and look at the Intent that you get. Either that, or add some logging that prints out the contents of the Intent and its EXTRAS. I assume that you aren't getting the EXTRAS that you think you should be getting.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/ConnectionTest/src/com/varma/samples/conntest/MainActivity.java) is a sample class that shows you how to do it. I think this is exactly what you need and it might help resolve your issue. In this sample the BroadcastReceiver is registered programmatically instead of the Manifest, but I think it won't be a problem for you.

Let me know if works.